# Maven Surefire: Running tests in specified dependencies

Tags: java, maven, maven-surefire-plugin

I have a project that includes multiple other jar artifacts as dependencies. I'm using the surefire plugin's `dependenciesToScan` property to run tests in the said artifacts as follows:

```
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.18.1</version>
      <configuration>
        <dependenciesToScan>
          <dependency>com.example.tests:project-a</dependency>
          <dependency>com.example.tests:project-b</dependency>
        </dependenciesToScan>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>

<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.example.tests</groupId>
    <artifactId>project-a</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.example.tests</groupId>
    <artifactId>project-b</artifactId>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Ideally, I would like to be able to do the following:

- `mvn test` would run the tests in each dependency like normal
- Another parameter would run *only* the tests for whichever artifact is specified and skip the tests for whatever dependency was not included

Is this possible at all or is there another way to approach this?

Comment: Why not running the unit tests in the appropriate modules directly ?

Comment: This is in an 'aggregate' project that is used to run all the various different artifacts at once, for example, in a Jenkins job. Would you suggest just keeping them separate?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [profiles](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html) to have two distinct builds.

```
<profiles>
  <profile>
    <id>project-a</id>
    <build>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.18.1</version>
          <configuration>
            <dependenciesToScan>
              <dependency>com.example.tests:project-a</dependency>
            </dependenciesToScan>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
     </plugins>
   </build>
  </profile>
  <profile>
    <id>project-b</id>
    <build>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.18.1</version>
          <configuration>
            <dependenciesToScan>
              <dependency>com.example.tests:project-b</dependency>
            </dependenciesToScan>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
     </plugins>
   </build>
  </profile>
</profiles>
```

The use `mvn clean test -P project-a` or `mvn clean test -P project-b`
You could also set different properties in each profiles and have a centralized surefire config.

---

Or you could use a property:

```
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.18.1</version>
      <configuration>
        <dependenciesToScan>
          <dependency>${someProperty}</dependency>
        </dependenciesToScan>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

The use `mvn clean test -DsomeProperty=project-a`

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply! What about when there are more than just a couple dependencies? Say there are numerous test jars...is there any way to prevent from having to have a profile for each one that gets added?

Comment: If you have too many "project-x" then you can always use a property to specify the "<dependency>"